# Registering .net 4 dll on Clients Machines

Tags: .net-4.0, client, config, regasm, mapped-drive

I have some programs that some of them built with vb6 and others are .net 
and all of them runs in many client machines,

vb6 programs uses some of the dlls of .net programs and because of this,
i always have to register these .net dlls on client machines.

i use a batch file to register my dlls on client machines with some lines of command like this one :

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe" "M:\SharedLibraries\XPST.dll"
```

because of some reasons i upgraded my .net programs to .net framework 4.

so for using .net 4, i changed my registering command to something like this :

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "M:\SharedLibraries\XPST4.dll"
```

but in .net 4 it gives me the error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///M:\SharedLibraries\XPST4.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

i know that i can solve it by adding the ''loadFromRemoteSources''
tag to file ''regasm.exe.config'' 
but i must do it on every client machine that it's not my favorite option !

could you show me a better solution ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to register it with administrator privileges?

Comment: @Stefan yes users have admin rights for their local machines.

Comment: There are still a couple of thing that might prevent registration: 1) Is the file at that location? 2) Are all the dependencies registered or on that location? 3) Try to run the command from the working directory `M:\SharedLibraries` 4) If they come from a network source, check the file properties if the assembly is `blocked` (although this would be as much effort as  the `loadFromRemoteSources` change. ... Anyhow, you hit a security issue here, so it's unlikely to bypass this easily. Maybe you can use a powershell script.

Comment: @Stefan those files are on the location and dependencies are located there too, i'll check other things you've said, thank you

Comment: loadFromRemoteSources is probably the better option, as you may already know, since CLR version 4.0 a security setting has been applied that affect exactly what your'e trying to do - register a dll from a network-shared drive. would you consider adding a 'Copy' to that batch, to copy the DLL to a local drive and then registering it there instead ?

Comment: @polisha989, the way you said didn't work. thank you anyway.

Comment: @eFarzad didn't work is not descriptive enough for me to help, when you copy to C:\<some-other-folder>\yourdllfile.dll and regasm to that path, what error are you getting ?

Comment: @polisha989 files get registersed at _C:\<some-other-folder>\yourdllfile.dll_, but when i run the exe file on the network, it works like if those files are not registered.